# dumping mysql database in putty

Tags: mysql, windows, putty, dump

I'm currently using putty but am having trouble getting the dump command to work. I've searched around but haven't been able to get this to work. I'm entering in;

mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p lab1 > lab1dump.sql

but when I enter the command it just goes to the next line, like it's looking for more input. Am I missing something? I'm brand new to MYSQL.

I'm also not sure where this file would go after I do dump it. Is there a default location for these files?

Answer (score 1):

You should enter your password in the next line (for the user `root`).
Dump would be in the current folder, you should see it with `ls` command.

Also, in case it's `localhost` you can omit `-h` parameter.

Comment: It's not asking for a password, though. After I press enter it goes down to the next line. It looks like this

    mysql> mysqldump -uroot -p lab1 >lab1dump.sql
    ->

If I try to enter a password it goes to the next line like it's still waiting for me to input more information.

Comment: the last "->" is on the next line. Sorry for formatting.

Comment: it looks you are trying to enter your command in mysql command line.

You should enter it (`mysqldump ...`) right after you connected to the machine with putty, under normal session.

Comment: I figured it out. I guess I have to exit the database that I'm currently using to dump? Thanks for the help!